# Convert rails association to shouldamatcher syntax using regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I am working on a ruby on rails project. I am trying to convert

`'has_many :comments,:as=>:entity,:order=>"id asc", :dependent => :destroy'`

to look like this

`it { should have_many(:comments).as(:entity).order("id asc").dependent(:destroy)}`

I am almost successful in doing so . The only problem I face is in a part of it. The regex I am using to find the key value pairs inside the string is

`'has_many :comments,:as=>:entity,:order=>"id asc", :dependent => :destroy'.scan(/:\w+\s*=>\s*.\w+/)` which returns

```
#=> [":as=>:entity", ":order=>\"id", ":dependent => :destroy"]
```

Its not able to return the full string inside any of the values. It just takes the first word which is quite evident from the regex.

I want a result like this :

`#=> [":as=>:entity", ":order=> "id asc", ":dependent => :destroy"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
'has_many :comments,:as=>:entity,:order=>"id asc", :dependent => :destroy'.scan(/:\w+\s*=>\s*.[\w \"\']+/)
```